# How can I simulate physics on my curved LED strip?

Tags: physics, python

I have a LED strip with 300 LEDs that I can control one by one:

- https://github.com/cipold/pyledstrip

You can think of them as Adafruit NeoPixels:

- https://www.adafruit.com/category/168

I have code to detect the physical positions of all LEDs using a camera and generate an x/y heightmap:

- https://github.com/cipold/pyledstrip-detector

There is some experimental code to make use of the heightmap and let pixels race along the strip like on a rollercoaster:

- https://github.com/Pixe1/pyledstrip-particles
- Video: http://mnagel.net/oneshot/2018-03-02/particle.mp4/975a194be7cc6fc8/particle.mp4

The "physics engine" within that code is very ad-hoc, however. I want to rewrite it into something that more explicitly encodes the physical laws of classical/Newtonian mechanics.

I can easily simulate particles with mass, position, velocity (acceleration/gravity/forces). With multiple particles and gravity between them, I would end up with some kind of solar system. Or with constant overall gravity, one particle would fall down in a straight line, accelerating all the time.

What I really want is "global gravity" but restrict the particles to move along the path dictated by the LED strip/heightmap of waypoints (one degree of freedom along that path). How can I adequately model this restriction with formulas that are still reasonably physically accurate?

Comment: It sounds like we could ignore all the LED details and just ask "how can I simulate Newtonian mechanics for a point mass constrained to a curved rail" - is that accurate? Do you model the curve as a series of line segments, or Bézier/other spline types?

Comment: Yes, especially with the reworded question more focused on implementing it all myself, that is basically what it boils down to. It is still helpful to know some background, imho.
Currently I have the position as float in the interval (0, LED_COUNT) with fractional parts being interpreted as partway between two LEDs lighting them both proportionally. So basically it is a series of line segments.

Comment: But I have no problem with fitting a spline through the LEDs if this helps. The results should be good enough with linear interpolation because the LEDs have a constant, small distance between them. But if the math gets easier/clearer I will calculate a spline.

Comment: Just to clarify: you don't have to implement it all yourself, and it's entirely valid for answers to say "use this library and implement it like so..." — we just don't accept "which library should I use?" as the core question. Keeping the focus on solving the problem, rather than selecting tech, generally produces more constructive answers.